# Updating AJAX success with dynamic data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am not very good with JavaScript, but am trying to better myself. I am refactoring a script that has 2 virtually identical AJAX calls. The only difference between the two is what's being done inside the success function.

If I wanted to use one AJAX function instead of 2, how would I go about 'injecting' one or the other blocks of code into what would be the single success function?

Here is what I have right now.

```
$(".one").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url      : "upload.asp",
    type     : "POST",
    data     : $("#upload").serialize(),
    dataType : 'json',
    cache    : false,
    success  : function(data) {
      // do some stuff here
    }
  });
});

$(".two").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url      : "upload.asp",
    type     : "POST",
    data     : $("#upload").serialize(),
    dataType : 'json',
    cache    : false,
    success  : function(data) {
      // do some different stuff here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Nan, you'll want to share some of your code and explain what you've tried that isn't working so far.

Comment: add your code and let us help you.

Comment: There you go, guys. Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something the following will help:

```
methodOne = function(data) {
  // do some stuff
};
methodTwo = function(data) {
  // do some different stuff
};

$(".one, .two").click(function() {
  var callback = function(){};
  if ($(this).hasClass('one')) {
    callback = methodOne;
  else if ($(this).hasClass('two')) {
    callback = methodTwo;
  }
  $.ajax({
    url      : "upload.asp",
    type     : "POST",
    data     : $("#upload").serialize(),
    dataType : 'json',
    cache    : false,
    success  : callback
  });
});
```

Comment: Aguardientico, I really don't know much about JavaScript. I see a few different types of solutions. Your solution seems to use a callback. Can you please compare what you have against what @Muhammad Omer Aslam posted and tell me which one is better to use? His code doesn't seem to use a callback.

Comment: i have deleted my answer as this answer would work if you want to execute different operations in `success` callback depending upon which button was clicked , +1for this answer.  @NaN

Comment: Got it. Thank you Aguardientico. It's too bad that Muhammad deleted his post because I wanted to ask you *why* his solution wouldn't work. His solution also seemed to be tied to the AJAX completed function which I would think would give me what I needed. I'm trying to learn more about this and when I should use one method over another

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, Thanks Muhammad. I'm unclear why your solution wouldn't work though. You were tied to the complete function of the AJAX function, so wouldn't that be synchronous?

Comment: neither would be synchronous @NaN neither mine or this but this is a better way to write the code plus my solution was using single `success` function for both the `.one` and `.two` and if i had to reformat  it would be similar to this answer, this is the reason to delete my answer , now if you want to make `ajax` synchronous add the option `async: false`  to the ajax call and you will see the difference although this has been [**deprecated**](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) so eventually you have to use `promise`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a new function for the Ajax call and pass in the element that was clicked as a parameter like so:

```
function MyCall(el) {
  $.ajax({
    url      : "upload.asp",
    type     : "POST",
    data     : $("#upload").serialize(),
    dataType : 'json',
    cache    : false,
    success  : function(data) {
      if(el == "one"){
        //Do something
      }
      if(el == "two"){
        //Do something else
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Then call it in your click function like so:

```
$(".one").click(function() {
  MyCall("one");
});

$(".two").click(function() {
  MyCall("two");
});
```

Comment: Ok, so I can do it this way? Even though AJAX is synchronous, this is still acceptable? I thought I may have needed a callback when it's synchronous

Comment: I mean, synch vs asynch shouldn't really matter in this case,unless you need to wait for the success callback before allowing the other element to be clicked...

Comment: I do need to add a loader.gif and then remove that class when the AJAX is done. Also there are a couple other things that should be on hold until the request is completed. This is kind of why I decided to refactor this thing

Comment: Then you will need to incorporate all that logic into the ajax callbacks

Comment: OK, I'm glad I asked. Would Aguardientico's solution give me that?

Comment: @NaN AJAX is not synchronous by default.

Comment: I may be wrong on my understanding, but I thought synchronous meant that what happens inside the AJAX success function is dependent on the response back from the server. Am I right on this?